# javascript for loop, jquery id generation and recognition

Tags: javascript, jquery

var product="";
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        product+=""+i+"";
        $("#"+i).hover(function()
        {
            alert(i);
        });
    }

product variable is able to generate the desired output with the div ids ,but when I m moving my mouseover those divs, that mouseover function(from jquery) is not working/called.

Please help

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    $("<div align='center' width='88' />")
    .text(i)
    .attr('id', 'id' + i)
    .bind('mouseenter mouseleave', {counter: i}, function()
    {
        alert(event.data.counter);
    })
    .attachTo(someDOMNode);
}
```

A few comments:

- [IDs must not start with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)
- Be careful when creating closures in a loop, because the loop variable `i` will have the value from the last iteration in any closure (i.e. every `alert(i)` will alert `10`) (See [JavaScript Closures for Dummies](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html) - Example 5). That is why I use [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) here. The events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are the ones, `hover()` binds the handler to. And to overcome the problem with `i`, I pass the value of `i` as event data.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is that `product` isn't part of the DOM when you try to assign a function to it. `$("#"+i)` will return an empty list.

Comment: Even with that it would not work properly because of the way the OP is generating the closure in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering that if in your code where the DIV string has been attached to DOM. I believe there is some code where you have done this.